# Algorithm for solving systems of linear equations mod 2 over non-square matrix

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics

I am trying to write an algorithm that finds a solution to a system of linear xor equations $A x = b$ where A is a $n \times m$ boolean matrix with (possibly) more columns than rows $(n < m)$. I have implemented a variant of Gaussian elimination along the lines of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483925/how-to-implementing-gaussian-elimination-for-binary-equations). However, since there are more variables than equations, I am still left with a (simplified) system of equations that needs to be solved after $A$ has been reduced.

I was looking up on computing the pseudo-inverse for $A$ with singular value decomposition implementations but I feel like this is overkill for this case of linear boolean equations. Is there a more clever way? Also I have checked out several C++ libraries, however none of them supports non square boolean matrices and corresponding XOR operations. Also I used SageMath's `.solve_right()` to check and it does yield solutions for the examples I have tried out - so for my particular test cases there indeed seem to be solutions for the system of equations.

As example consider the matrix $A$ (which is already reduced):

$A = \left(\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &1 &1 \\ 
0 &1 &0 &1 &1 &0 &1 \\ 
0 &0 &1 &0 &1 &1 &1\\ 
\end{array}\right)$

and

$b = (0, 1, 0)$

How can I algorithmically solve the system now to obtain the solution (computed with SageMath) $x = (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I think the utility of the pseudo inverse is when you have an overdetermined system (more rows than columns).  That is, your system may not have a solution in the exact sense, but it may have a closest solution, which may be computed using pseudoinverse.  Your problem is solving an underdetermined system, which may have infinitely many solutions.  So, your algorithm should reduce your matrix sufficiently to find a solution, and then supply a parameterisation of the full solution space.

Comment: I imagine that Sage is just looking at the first three columns of $A$ because this $3 \times 3$ matrix is invertible.  So that's one way to do it:  Use Gaussian elimination.  If the first $n \times n$ matrix is invertible, solve it for $x$ and set all other coordinates of $x$ to zero.

Comment: @Doug yes you are right, the system in the example is underdetermined. How would a compuation of a parameterisation of the solutions space look like approximately (in the sense of how could this be solved numerically?)

Comment: For completeness' sake: I found the C library FLINT can solve exactly these problems (e.g. the module `nmod_mat`)